# Passing aws credentials as windows ENV variables to dockerfile

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a django project that i am trying to deploy in aws, i am using the parameter store to store my secret  keys, so i need to pass the aws credentials and the region otherwise i am getting an error each time i want to create the docker image that the aws credentials are missing, i have tried to pass those credentials as windows env variables using the `setx variable value`   i am able to get the correct value when i run `echo %variable%` on the cmd, i have added this to the docker file

```
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
```

i was getting always the same error so i have added this cmd to print the variables that i have in the container when creating the image

```
Run printenv
```

i have got the logic output is that the three variables are empty so i assume that the docker file is not accessing those variables, i don't know if it is a permission problem or if some one got the same error as mine,

I have also passed those values to the docker-compose file

```
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
```

But the dockerfile is not getting the variables values in both cases.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: how you build or run the container? and why you need AWS keys in container when you can use role?

Comment: i am building the container using docker-compose up -d, and how can i use roles ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, you should avoide to use `AWS keys` if you are working in AWS environment, better to assign [role to the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) base on you requirement.

---

`RUN printenv` will print environment variable if it set during build time, So better to no go for this option, as keeping keys in Docker image is really risky.

Set ENV during run time.

Place All environment variable `.env` file as simple `docker-compose up` will not set environment variable unless you place in dot env or export in host.

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
└── .env
```

.env will be like

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=mykey
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=mysecret
```

Now, all set to print and verify ENV

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    image: node:alpine
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
    command: sh -c "node -e 'console.log(process.env)'"
```

the output should be like

```
Attaching to set-env-docker-compose-build_node_1
node_1  | {
node_1  |   NODE_VERSION: '12.10.0',
node_1  |   HOSTNAME: '644ba6300f6b',
node_1  |   YARN_VERSION: '1.17.3',
node_1  |   SHLVL: '2',
node_1  |   HOME: '/root',
node_1  |   AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: '',
node_1  |   PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
node_1  |   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'SOME_KEY',
node_1  |   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'SOME_SECRET',
node_1  |   PWD: '/'
node_1  | }
```